# Creating list within a container in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, list, echo, hybrid-mobile-app

I have tried creating a list within a container in PHP and I am struggling because it's my first time doing a list in PHP. I want the list within the container to look like an example I found on http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group this example is under "List Group" then it's the "Linked Items" example.

**My code**:

```
// List
      echo_lines(array(
// All cases
    "<ul>", 
      "<div class='row'>",
      "<div class='col-md-6'>",
      "<div class='panel panel-default'>",
      "<div class='panel-heading clearfix'>",
      "<h4 style='margin:0; margin-top:5px; padding:0;'>All Projects</h4>",
      "</div>",
        "<div class='panel-body'>",
        // Content
        "<div class='list-group'>"
          "<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>"Orange"</a>"
          "<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>"Pizza"</a>"
          "<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>"Beef"</a>"
          "<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>"Chicken"</a>"
    "</ul>",
```

Comment: You separate the items until you get to the list-group div, what's up with that?

Comment: You're also missing closing tags for every single div.

Comment: The rest of the page is done in PHP... I have the container working untill I add the content in

Comment: children of `ul` must be `li`; Your `"Orange"` quoting breaks your php lines, also some colons missed

Comment: But I get this error message "syntax error, unexpected '"<a href='#' class='list-group' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Pinder/CMS/event.php on line 421"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you gave us is way to messy. You don't close most of the html tags, and I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve

Here is the example from bootstrap documentation that you linked, more or less mixed with your code.
I'm still not sure if "Orange", "Beef", "Pizza" and "Chicken" are just string or you want to use variables (since you escaped them on your code)

```
$str = "";
$str .= '<div class="list-group">';
$str .= '   <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Orange</a>';
$str .= '   <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Beef</a>';
$str .= '   <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Pizza</a>';
$str .= '   <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Chicken</a>';
$str .= '   <a href="#" class="list-group-item">' . $variable . '</a>'; // this is an example, if you want to use variable
$str .= '</div>';
echo $str;
```

---

If you want to use `"` or `'` into a string, you have to escape it with a backslash `\` depending on how you write your string.

Example :

```
$str = "";
$str .= 'Here you can use "double quotes" without escaping<br />';
$str .= "There you will need to escape \"double quotes\"<br />";
$str .= 'There you will need to escape \'simple quotes\'<br />';
$str .= "There, escaping 'simple quotes' is unnecessary";
```

More info at [PHP: Strings manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score 0):

In `PHP` you must concatenate variables or constants to your string with the `.` operator, and you forgot to keep `>` within the quotation (`"`):

```
      "<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>". Orange. "</a>"
      "<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>". Pizza. "</a>"
      "<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>". Beef. "</a>"
      "<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>". Chicken. "</a>"
```

Also, why are you sometimes using commas and sometimes not?

Comment: I still get the "syntax error, unexpected '"<a href='#' class='list-group' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Pinder/CMS/event.php on line 421" error message

Comment: @TheGarrett I recommend that you do it like _everyone else_ and echo it properly without using an array, try one line at a time and concatenate the string.

Comment: @Jonast92 i doubt OP knows about constants, let alone variables. i think he really just wanted them as literal strings, and got confused / messed up the formatting of `"<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>Orange</a>"`

Comment: I copied that from an example... I justed changed the text (content of the list) if you had read the question...

Answer (score -1):

Use php array :

```
<?php

$arr_foods = array('Orange', 'Pizza','Beef', 'Chicken');
$str_list_group = '';
foreach($arr_foods as $str_food) 
{
//Concatenation
    $str_list_group =.  "<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>". $str_food. "</a>\n";

}
print $str_list_group;

?>
```